# Codeigniter error in adding functions

Tags: php, codeigniter

im creating my first site with codeigniter.
Im trying to put editing function and i have error:

Severity: Notice Message: 
Undefined index: program 
Filename: controllers/news.php Line Number: 21

here code of controller:

```
<?php
class News extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct(); 
    $this->load->model('news_model');
}
public function index() 
{
$data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
$data['program'] = 'News archive';
$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/sidebar');
$this->load->view('news/index', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
public function view($id)
{
$data = array('news_item' => $this->news_model->get_news($id));
$data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($id);
$data['program'] = $data['news_item']['program']; // ERROR IS HERE
$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/sidebar');
$this->load->view('news/view', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
if (empty($data['news_item']))
{
    show_404();
}
 }
public function create(){
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$data['title'] = 'Создать';
$this->form_validation->set_rules('program', 'Программа', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('code', 'Код', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('course', 'Направление', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('form', 'Форма обучения', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('time', 'Срок обучения', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Стоимость', 'required');    
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('accreditation', 'Аккредитация', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('department', 'Кафедра', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('level', 'Уровень', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('type', 'Тип ОП', 'required');
if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
{
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/sidebar');
    $this->load->view('news/create');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
else
{
    $this->news_model->set_news();
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/sidebar');
    $this->load->view('news/formsuccess');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
}
 public function edit($id) { // передаем ид для редактирования
 $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
 $this->load->library('validation');
 if (!$this->input->post('id') && !$this->input->post('program')) {
   $news_item = $this->news_model->get($id);
   $this->validation->id = $news_item['id'];
   $this->validation->program = $news_item['program'];
 }
 $data = array();
 if ($this->validation->run() === FALSE)
 {
 $this->load->view('form', $data);
 }
 else
{
   $data = array(
    'program' => $this->input->post('program'),
    'code' => $this->input->post('code'),
    'course' => $this->input->post('course'),
    'form' => $this->input->post('form'),
    'time' => $this->input->post('time'),
    'price' => $this->input->post('price'),
    'accreditation' => $this->input->post('accreditation'),
    'department' => $this->input->post('department'),
    'level' => $this->input->post('level'),
    'type' => $this->input->post('type')
 );
   $this->news_model->update($data);
   redirect('/news');
}
}
}
```

Comment: @PuzzledBoy `$data['program'] = $data['news_item']['program']; // ERROR IS HERE`

Comment: These both lines are doing the same job. `$data = array('news_item' => $this->news_model->get_news($id));
$data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($id);` Get rid of any one and try.

Comment: Check var_dump($data['program']); in controller. What output it gives ? post here.

Comment: i added var_dump($data['program']); and i dont have this problem, but now on the page of edition it says "404 page not found"

Comment: What does `vardump($this->news_model->get_news($id));exit()` show? Basically what this error means is that the index you're looking for hasn't be set.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined index Error message is invoked when a variable or value for an array index is not defined.

try

```
var_dump($data['news_item']);
```

Does it print the data type as Object ? if its object
try

```
$data['program'] = $data['news_item']->program; // ERROR IS HERE
```

If these doesn't help, please post the output of the following line,
 This will help everyone here to fix your problem

```
var_dump($data['news_item']);
```